# Object can not be resolved

Tags: java, listeners

I have this code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
public Window(){
    ...

    JButton button = new JButton("OK");
    getContentPane().add(button);

    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
    button.addActionListener(handler);
    ...
}

private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        if (event.getSource() == button){ // <--- "button can not be resolved"
            System.out.println("Hello");

        }               
    }
}
```

I'm getting that error in Eclipse. I just made a (simplified) example found in a book, dont know what can be wrong. Knowledge eye required! :)

Comment: As an aside, it may be confusing to name a class after one of its superclasses. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid having your ActionListener action dependent on what button was pressed. If you have different actions for different buttons then define a seperate ActionListener for each action.

That way your listener doesn't need to check what button was pressed.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `button` object is not visible in class `ButtonHandler`; it's local to the `Window` constructor. You can make it a field in `Window` or find out what command was intended from the [`ActionEvent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html). See the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more.

Addendum: for example

```
if ("OK".equals(event.getActionCommand())) { ...
```

Comment: Think you meant it wasn't visible to class ButtonHandler

Answer (score 1):

There is away of making the button handler aware of which button is responding to, but this will prevent you from using the same object.

make a new constructor that takes the button object is a key

```
//...
ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler(button); 
//...
```

and then

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
    private JButton button;

    ButtonHandler( JButton button) { this.button = button; }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){   

    if (event.getSource() == button){ // <--- "button can not be resolved"   
        System.out.println("Hello");   

    }                  
}
```